# LED Strip Controller - Can someone check over my schematic?

Tags: microcontroller, led, pcb, boost

This is my first time designing a circuit with any kind of computer program, and before I ordered all the components and PCBs I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making any rookie mistakes since the whole circuit is made up from datasheet examples and answered questions on forums. I've gone over it myself a couple times, but since I haven't done this before I don't know what I'm looking for mistake-wise.

[image: Schematic]

My major concern is that the boost circuit on the left side isn't going to work, but I'm also worried that I don't have the right connections on the MOSFETs or the ICSP header.

Comment: You'll need some bypass caps (one for each VCC/AVCC pin). I haven't checked the gate capacitance but you could add some gate resistors and pull down resistors on the FETs.

Comment: R1 looks like it's on the wrong side of D1.

Comment: Also, I'm *pretty* sure you have the wrong resistor values according to the datasheet. EDIT: OH, they're backwards, that's why.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, I must've read the datasheet diagram wrong, divider is on the right side of the diode now. :)

Comment: Max Gate threshold voltage on the IRF3710 is 4.0V. That's marginal for 5V drive.

Comment: I would suggest adding breakout pins to all the pins of the atmega328. That way, you can use it as a proper arduino, as well as having your custom circuitry

Comment: There's no 5V regulator on board? Missing caps on MCU supply pins. Is there an internal pull-up on the reset? Otherwise external pull-up is required. The main concern here should be the boost regulator layout - it will have heavy impact on how noisy the supply (and the board as whole) ends up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news. You've picked mosfets that can work with a 5V gate voltage. Not the best case, you might experience fairly high Rds(on) and they might become warm.

[image]

I'm not sure of the purpose of the booster. Why do you need 24V LED strips when there are also lots of strips for 12V?

However, this 2A boost converter could work. The board layout is very important at 1.2 MHz though.
I would recommend for a first design with switchmode supplies to stay in the  KHz switching range.

I also have a few other remarks:
 - Add an LC input filter to prevent noise upstream.
 - Add more than 22uF output capacitance.
 - Make sure the gates and the on/off are at a known level during reset with some pull-up/down resistors.
 - Add at least some 100nf and 1uf ceramics around the chip, and preferably some 10uF electrolytic near the connector.

I can't comment on the ISP connector, this will be entirely up to the symbol/footprint connections.

Comment: Most commercial controllers of this sort are designed to play well with both 12V and 24V LED strips.   24V has the annoyance of being "different" and having twice the cut distance, but all the advantages of double voltage/half current.

Comment: The 24V bootst is because I have a surplus of them currently, and because I'm working on a more complex design that is going to depend on one, so I'd rather mess it up now than later. How much output capacitance would be reasonable?

Comment: I have a surplus of 24V LED strips, just to clarify.